# Silverlight client identity not always passed to server?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, identity, basichttpbinding

I have a Silverlight client that has some problems talking to the server it originates from via a WCF `basicHttpBinding`. The service configuration is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="silverlightBinding">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="MyServices.ImportService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="MyServices.IImportService"
                bindingConfiguration="silverlightBinding" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The server is an IIS6 web server that is configured to use integrated authentication. The application pool identity is a domain account.

Now some calls from the Silverlight client to the web server include the client identity (the domain user that accesses the client) and some do not! I have included a part of the IIS log to show this:

```
2009-12-09 14:10:00 W3SVC1490499214 10.0.0.113 GET /ClientBin/MySLApp.xap - 80 BROWNIE\TestUser 10.0.0.216 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1) 304 0 0
2009-12-09 14:12:33 W3SVC1490499214 10.0.0.113 POST /Services/ImportService.svc - 80 - 10.0.0.216 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1) 401 2 2148074254
2009-12-09 14:12:33 W3SVC1490499214 10.0.0.113 POST /Services/ImportService.svc - 80 - 10.0.0.216 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1) 401 2 2148074254
2009-12-09 14:12:33 W3SVC1490499214 10.0.0.113 POST /Services/ImportService.svc - 80 - 10.0.0.216 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1) 401 1 0
2009-12-09 14:12:33 W3SVC1490499214 10.0.0.113 POST /Services/ImportService.svc - 80 BROWNIE\TestUser 10.0.0.216 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1) 200 0 0
2009-12-09 14:12:33 W3SVC1490499214 10.0.0.113 POST /Services/ImportService.svc - 80 - 10.0.0.216 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1) 401 1 0
2009-12-09 14:12:34 W3SVC1490499214 10.0.0.113 POST /Services/ImportService.svc - 80 BROWNIE\TestUser 10.0.0.216 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1) 200 0 0
2009-12-09 14:12:34 W3SVC1490499214 10.0.0.113 POST /Services/ImportService.svc - 80 - 10.0.0.216 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1) 401 1 0
2009-12-09 14:12:34 W3SVC1490499214 10.0.0.113 POST /Services/ImportService.svc - 80 BROWNIE\TestUser 10.0.0.216 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1) 200 0 0
```

If you scroll a little to the right, you see that for some requests an identity is known (`BROWNIE\TestUser`). For most requests, however, this is not the case. It's as if the client 'randomly' chooses when to send an identity along.

Has anyone ever seen this behavior and found a solution?

Comment: Are actually experiencing any problems with the way the application works?

Comment: Yes, an authentication popup is shown on the client browser after some time. And the client application stops working after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced similar behaviour with a silverlight app.. turned out to be one of these problems:

[WCF bug 1](http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/433569/wcf-throws-an-executionengineexception-when-returning-an-array-as-ilist-t)

[WCF bug 2](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=391260&lc=1043)

[Blog infosupport](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/jonathan/archive/2007/08/15/Possible-WCF-Serialization-Issue_3F00_.aspx)

It does not happen in Windows 7, but on some windows Server versions it does.. can't remember which.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like 3 standard authentication handshakes (2 401's each) followed by a succesful access (200).  If you are seeing a lot of these in quick succession then this indicates that connections to the server are not being re-used for subsequent access.  I'm not a wcf expert it could be that this is normal, although I'd  be disappointed if this could not be configured away some how.

Comment: This seems to be the case, but this is because I removed some unauthenticated requests to shorten the post. In reality, there are about 30 unauthenticated requests and only 5 authenticated.